# Как записать значение в указанную на скрине ячейку в dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как записать значение в указанную на скрине ячейку  в dataGridView?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я дошел до Cells, дальше что смотреть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значение считываю c XML файла

Comment: dataGridView .Rows[ y ].Cells[  x ]  и смотрите что там добалено. Смотреть только после загрузки файла (или после DataBind)

Comment: Что вы хотите туда добавить и для чего? может проще добавить еще одну колонку и туда писать то что вам надо?!

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать в обработчике события прорисовки ячейки:

```
private void DataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("text", e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Однако, как правильно предложили в комментариях, лучше добавить ещё одну колонку.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void UpdateDGV()
{
    dgvMain.Rows.Clear();
    dgvMain.ColumnCount = 8;
    string[] name = { "a0", "a1", "a2"};
    for(int i= 0; i < dgvMain.ColumnCount; i++){
        dgvMain.Columns[i].Name = name[i];
        dgvMain.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }

    double[] array = new double[]{76.5, -0.04, 0.04};

    List<double> list = new List<double[]>();
    list.add(array);

    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        string[] tmp = new string[item.lenghth];
        for (int i = 0; i < item.lenghth; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = item[i].ToString();
        }
        dgvMain.Rows.Add(tmp);
    }
}
```